# How to fix sending JSESSIONID from cookie on page reload?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security

According to the [spring-boot-oauth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) manual, after OAuth2 authorization we have a JSESSIONID and it is enough for basic security.
But when updating the f5 page, session cookies are deleted and the first requests after the update cause an authorization error.
In my case the status is set to 401 (Spring boot 3.2):

```
http.exceptionHandling(exHandler ->
                exHandler.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)));
```

As an Angular17 client (localhost:4200):

```
export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const clonedRequest = req.clone( { withCredentials: true } );
  return next(clonedRequest);
};
```

When the JSESSIONID is received, everything works without errors in the Angular console, but if you reload the page, an error will appear in the angular console log:

```
status: 401,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/api...',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api...: 401 ',
  error: null
```

At the same time, the same request is processed and produces the result, i.e. First, one request will receive an error, and then a normal response. In the browser, all requests are displayed with a status of 200.

When we reload the page, the login page set in the handler is displayed for a split second:

```
export const errorInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const router = inject(Router);
  return next(req).pipe(catchError(err => {
    if (err.status === 401) {
      router.navigate(['/']);
    }
    return throwError(err);
  }));
};
```

Spring config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2LoginSuccessHandler oauth2LoginSuccessHandler;

    @Value("${spring.security.cors.allowed-origin}")
    private String allowedOrigin;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
            CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
            corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin(allowedOrigin);
            corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            return corsConfiguration;
        }));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests ->
                authorizeHttpRequests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll() // CORS
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

        http.oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> {
                    oauth2Login.successHandler(oauth2LoginSuccessHandler);
                    oauth2Login.failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("error.message", exception.getMessage());
                        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                    });
                }
        );

        http.exceptionHandling(exHandler ->
                exHandler.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)));

        http.httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

[angular console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Q0G.png)

Comment: A reload should not delete a session cookie. What browser do you use?

Comment: _But when updating the f5 page_ what is the F5 page?

Comment: @dur, you're right, thx, i found the problem, it can be reproduced if use Angular SSR